# How do I make a jQuery loop which changes the href attribute of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've built a slideshow gallery from scratch using `jQuery`. It can have any number of slides. Under the slideshow I have a 'More info' button. I would like this link to change every 5000ms to reflect the slide being show.

I know I can use `.attr` to change the `href` value itself, it is just changing it at intervals of 5000ms to different things (on a loop!) that I'm completely at a loss with...

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

```
//Set Image to first picture by default.
$('#yourImageId').attr("src", imageSrcArray[0]);

var milliseconds = 5000;

//Call Function after 5 seconds to show second picture
var t=setTimeout("changeSlide();", milliseconds); 

//If you set the image's original src to your first array item, this will cause the first update in 5 seconds to display the second item.
var cnt=1; 

function changeSlide(){

    //update image src
    $('#yourImageId').attr("src", imageSrcArray[cnt]);

    t=setTimeout("changeSlide();", milliseconds);//Call Function Again after 5 seconds

    cnt++;

    //Check that cnt is within image array bounds
    if (cnt > imageSrcArray.length-1) cnt=0;

}
```

Comment: Why pass a string to `setTimeout`? Just pass a function pointer. Evals are potentially evil. ie `setTimeout(changeSlide, milliseconds);`

Comment: Why not use `setInterval` instead of calling `setTimeout` every function call?

Comment: because this way, image load time is not taken out of the 5000 ms. The timer is not started until the image loads.